# NSPopupButton Default State and Bindings

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspopupbutton

I have a NSPopupButton tied to an array controller for content/value and I did have it tied to a property in the view controller.. all was working just fine. Then I needed to have a default value for the popup which is in Shared User Defaults.. this is where it all goes wrong !  If I change the "Selected Value" to have model key path of my user default.. removed the binding to my local property.   And also changes the default which I do not want (I do this in the Preferences window).

For now I gave got around it with code that looks up the required mnaged object by NSString from the popup as so :[[_qualifierPopup selectedCell] title]...  but this is very clunky !

So two quesitons:

1. can I have a NSPopupbutton's default state set by a Shared User Default - if so how ?
2. considering before the popup was bound to user default it was bound to a property of type id which returned the correct managed object, can I retrieve from the popup the same id rather than a string and doing a lookup on that string ?  If so can someone helpme with the syntax.

Thanks
Ian